# Upload multiple-photos to belongs_to model (jquery-fileupload-rails)

Tags: jquery, file-upload, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to upload multiple photos to model upload from 'new' form of model 'house' using jquery-upload-rails.

I'm using:

- Rails 4
- paperclip gem
- jquery-fileupload-rails gem

I have:

- scaffold 'house' (has_many uploads)
- scaffold 'upload' (for uploaded photos) (belongs_to house)

I can:

- Create new houses thru scaffold house (without photos)
- Upload photos thru scaffold upload with jquery-fileupload

I need:

One page, where user entering some info about house (country, city, adress and etc.) and select some photos with jquery-fileupload. When he press 'Create house' button photos are uploaded and house is created. Of course, house_id column in upload model for new photos must be the id of the house just created.

My files:

- models/house.rb:

  ```
  has_many :uploads
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :allow_destroy => true
  ```
- models/upload.rb

  ```
  belongs_to :house
  has_attached_file :upload, :styles => { :large => "800x800", :medium => "400x400>", :small => "200x200>" }
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  def to_jq_upload
  {
    "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
    "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
    "url" => upload.url(:original),
    "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
    "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
  }
  end
  ```
- controllers/houses_controller.rb:
  Everything standart, but

  ```
  params.require(:house).permit(..., uploads_attributes: [:upload, :house_id])
  ```
- controllers/uploads_controller.rb:
  Everything standart, but added render json to_jq_upload
- views/add/house.html.erb

  ```
  <%= form_for @house,  :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
  ...some inputs with house info...
  <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="house[uploads_attributes][][upload]" id="upload_upload">
  <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
  <% end %>
  ...script files...
  ```

So for now I can type in some information, select some photos, but there are two ways:

If I press start upload button near a photo, this photo is uploaded, new house is created, house_id is on it's place too. But this is only for one photo, when I click start upload on next photo, another one house is created with this photo.

If I press 'Create house' button, new house is created without any photos at all.

So I need onclick on the 'Create house' button photos are uploaded and new house is created.
Or when I click upload photo next to a photo, it gets uploaded to a model, but house_id is setted after I press 'Create house button'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured everything out.
Firstly, to make a button, that doesn't redirect to another page and let photos to upload I've used this code:

```
   <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar"> 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
      <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
      <span>Start upload</span>
    </button>
   </div>
```

Secondly, to make plugin to upload files in one post action, I have edited script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var num_added = 0;
    var added = 0;
    var all_data = {};
    $(function () {
        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
          complete: function (e, data) {
            window.location = "<%= root_url %>";
        },
          singleFileUploads: false
        })  .bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {num_added++;})
            .bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
            if(added < num_added)
            {
            if (added == 0)
            all_data = data;
            else
            {
            $.each(data['files'], function(i, file){
            all_data['files'].push(file);
            });
            $.each(data['context'], function(i, context){
            all_data['context'].push(context);
            });
            }
            added++;
            if (added == num_added)
            {
            added++;
            all_data.submit();
            }
            return false;
            }
            })
            .bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {num_added = 0; added = 0;});

        // 
        // Load existing files:
        $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
          var fu = $('#fileupload').data('blueimpFileupload'), 
            template;
          fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
          console.log(files);
          template = fu._renderDownload(files)
            .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
          // Force reflow:
          fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
            template[0].offsetWidth;
          template.addClass('in');
          $('#loading').remove();
        });

    });
  </script>
```